# How to store HTML tags in SQL 2008 Simple (taking HTML code as input in textbox and stored it in database)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$htmlCode="table style="backgr...")

Code:

```
    SqlConnection n_con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    n_con.Open();
    string N_Query = "update imageAd set code = '"+textbox1.text+"' where id = '" + id + "'";
    SqlCommand N_cmd = new SqlCommand(N_Query, n_con);
    N_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is `SQL 2008 Simple`?

Comment: Learn about parameterised queries, particularly if turning off request validation as mentioned by @jafarbtech

Answer (score 2):

Set `validateRequest="false"` in the `<%@ Page ... %>` directive in your .aspx

In .NET 4 you may need to do a little more. Sometimes it's necessary to also add `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` to web.config

**Note :** But this will cause script injection and Sql injection attacks possible in that page. Thats why it shows "A potentially dangerous". To prevent it use  `Lbel1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text)` when you displaying the html which u got input from this page. you can negotiate it if you are using in admin side of the webpage

Comment: Erm, doesn't this query have an enormous SQL injection vulnerability in it, and isn't that worth mentioning in your answer?